# how to instantiate a controller class with injection in play framework 2.5.x

Tags: scala, dependency-injection, playframework, playframework-2.5

I just upgraded the play framework to 2.5.x. I refactored the mail sending function with play mail 5.0.0. However, When i try to send the email, i get error that the parameter doesnt match the signature.

How can i instanitiate the MailHandler class without having to define a route?

```
class MailHandler @Inject()(mailer: MailerClient, val messagesApi: MessagesApi, environment: Environment) extends Controller with I18nSupport{
  def sendEmail(...) = {
  mailer.send(....)
```

}

```
controllers.mail.MailHandler m = new controllers.mail.MailHandler();
m.sendAuthenticationSubmitEmail(user.email, type);
```

Comment: Can you share the error message?

Answer (score 0):

If you're writing a piece of code that uses a component (`MailHandler` in your case) that uses dependency injection, you need to either pass in that dependency in the constructor (`new MailHandler(mailer, messagesAp, ..)`) or you need to inject that component as well.

In a typical play controller, this could look like this:

```
class MyController @Inject() (myMailerHandler: MailHandler) {
  m.sendAuthenticationSubmitEmail(user.email, type);
}
```